# How can a developer of fundamental software components best get the credit they deserve?

Tags: publications, research-process

Developing useful software products is becoming an increasingly important research activity in many fields.
However, it seems the proper credit/incentive system has not been fully worked out.

The situation becomes particularly problematic when large and complicated software products depends on many individual components developed by different research teams.

Consider a situation in which a researcher spend years of effort to develop a software component *C* that solves a very specific but very difficult fundamental problem. This researcher then publishes a paper on *C*.

Another group then develops a more general software *B* in a few weeks, which is a thin wrapper for *C*.  It basically reduces a more general class of problems to specialized problems that C can solve and then feed to *C*.  With everything being open source, *B* can directly incorporate *C* into itself in various ways.  Let's  assume this is done legally, and the README file in *B* contains flattering acknowledgement to *C*. This group then publishes a paper on *B*, which properly cites the original paper on *C*. (Best possible situation)

Fast forward a few years. Since *C* solves only very specific problems, no one uses it directly (other than *B*). The more general class of problems that *B* can solve (thanks to *C*) happened to become a hot topic. And the citation tally is now:

- *C*: 1 citation (just the paper on *B*);
- *B*: 1200 citations.

This seems like a terrible situation for the author of *C*. And this is not purely hypothetical. I have seen this happen to several people already.

More broadly, this credit/incentive structure may be bad for a field.  In particular, any one in tenure track position probably shouldn't be developing software for solving specific but fundamental problem (even though they are likely in a career stage in which they are most capable of doing exactly that).

My question is, taking what I described as given (I know it happens, so there's no point explaining why such situation does not exist), *how original developer of fundamental software components could position themselves (other than keeping things closed) to get proper credit*?

More broadly, *how can a field setup proper structure to incentivize the development of such software*?

Comment: Why is recognition in the form of citations important to you? Why don't you write B1, B2, ... BN yourself? Lots of papers only have one citation. Write more software. People who only write one paper don't normally get a lot of citations.

Comment: Maybe the insight that this software can be used generally is actually worth more than the software itself. But if that is not the case here: fortunately there are more and more scientists who can judge these situations correctly instead of only counting citations.

Comment: "*The whole thing that makes a mathematician’s life worthwhile is that he gets the grudging admiration of three or four colleagues.*" -- Donald Knuth, Computer Scientist

Comment: People who usually contributed to significant frameworks and components have pretty solid standing in the field and are highly regarded by community. People who volunteer their time to develop software are usually motivated by addressing certain problem. Success is measured in adoption of solution and that often results in commercial opportunities. A lot of papers on R-relate topics will be concerned with specific models, etc. but no one would question the role that R Core Team has in creating the language and making it available.

Comment: One idea is to develop a measure, similar to Google's PageRank algorithm, that measures papers not only by their direct citation count, but also by indirect count. So if C is cited by a highly-cited paper, the rank of C will increase too.

Comment: @Buffy, Yes, ideally the natural follow up work from the author of C should be B1, B2, ....   But there may be many obstacles, e.g., the lack of a broader understanding of the problems or lack of time.  Just generally speaking, it is possible that developing a tool for solving a single problem (C) and the higher level understanding of which tools can to solve what problems (B) require different skill set.

Comment: @usr1234567, Knuth neglected to say that a mathematician's life probably won't exist without getting the recognition from a hiring committee.

Comment: If B was so important, and follows immediately from C, then the researcher should have made B themselves. I'm sure you're familiar with the concept of low hanging fruit. Do you expect some kind of reward for neglecting to pick it? On the other hand, if perhaps B was not obvious, or B was more work than you imply, why should C get the credit for that work?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi But how can you tell the importance to a paper for each of its references? Paper B references paper C, but it references many other things also. Maybe it references stuff that doesn't work, as an example for how badly paper B is needed. Why should that stuff get credit for B's usefulness?

Comment: @CrisLuengo you are right. Counting citations is too crude a measure.

Answer (score 26):

Create a culture where evaluation of researchers is done by expert judgement rather than crude benchmarks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Say more?

Comment: The experts in the field know that C is more important than B - so if evaluation is done by expert judgement than C gets more credit than B.

Comment: Yes, if everyone did the right thing then the world would be a better place. However, ...

Comment: @Buffy I agree, that’s why I upvoted this answer for proposing that people (and universities) should do the right thing, and for explaining what “the right thing” is.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand we had that. It had good outcomes as well as bad. The big danger is cronyism.

Comment: Well, as much as I think that this is how it *should* be, this does not address the question, namely how the "original developer of fundamental software components could position themselves (other than keeping things closed) to get proper credit". This is something that the community should be doing. The developer with the 1 citation probably doesn't enough influence to make a noticeable difference. Also, it is reasonable to assume that these pea-counting habits will remain while hiring committees do not have the time to evaluate candidates extremely carefully...but will this ever change?

Comment: Once a metric becomes a target, it ceases to be a good metric

Comment: @Persistence: That is a (paraphrased) quote. What is the source?

Comment: Quoted in the 2021-11-29 Stack Overflow blog post *[The four engineering metrics that will streamline your software delivery](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/11/29/)* - [Goodhart's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodhart%27s_law) (1975): *"When a measure becomes a target, it ceases to be a good measure."*

Answer (score 7):

One thing is getting journals (and referees) better at referencing software dependencies. I've seen similar situations where large code B depends on some code C, everyone cites B but forgets to cite C. The only way is start yourself, making sure sure to cite everything, then when you referee papers, if they only cite B then request they cite C as well.

At the end of the day people should be citing the relevant literature, when they don't then your job as a referee is to request they do. Also when giving talks make sure to be more explicit that while you used B, that it is based on C to remind people about the link.

Comment: Isn't this a chicken-and-egg problem?  Most people will know the existence of C.  That's the problem.  If C is already well known, then of course there is no reason to count citations.

Answer (score 2):

> how original developer of fundamental software components could position themselves (other than keeping things closed) to get **proper credit**?

This is a very subjective question, since "proper" will be defined differently by different people. In the original Q OP mentions citations.

But citations are not even a measure of how useful something is. It is a combo of visibility of the original paper, PR campaign, having friends in the field, and how useful is the final product. That is not bad, because awesome but invisible or unusable software should not be rewarded.

So, the original developer should realize that *current scientific system* rewards very specific behaviors, where generating valuable products is only part of the equation.

If the want to develop fundamental components, they should:

- integrate their work into larger eco-system through collaborations
- spend time not only coding, but building community around their solutions or ideas
- they should not ship just the bare-bones solution, but a valuable toolkit that can be applied, or at least a protocol that will help others develop applications.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at your software license.  Why shouldn't it have a clause requiring that software that is using it require that papers that cite that (using) software *also* cite it?

If there was sufficient interest in a project group, or the community at whole, an open source software promoting organization, or a university, could task lawyers with creating such a license and the whole community would benefit.

(It would be not much different than, say, current BSD, which requires all using software, when distributed, to properly cite the copyrights of all BSD-licensed software it depends on, directly or indirectly.)

Comment: Is there any example of license?  I cannot think of any.  Also, if people don't even know about _C_, they certainly won't know what its license says.

Comment: If people are using C in their work sufficiently to cite it they will also know what its license says.  If not, that implies a great deal of disrespect of software and licenses in the academic research world which does not occur in the commercial world, where this is taken seriously.   And would be surprising, to me, because the academic world is itself very concerned with plagiarism.

Comment: I don’t think you understand how academic citations work. Authors cannot be legally mandated through a software license to cite someone’s work that they do not wish to cite. Such a requirement would be seen as blatantly unethical and would be completely unacceptable to both paper authors and journal editors. Personally if I ever ran across any software trying to impose such a requirement it’ll go straight into my trash bin, never to be looked at again.

Comment: @DanRomik - I do understand how academic citations work.  And your choice to not use software that carries such a license is indeed your choice.  Just as it is for the many commercial companies who also choose to use or not use software depending on (among other things) its license.  In this particular case, it would mean you couldn't use derived software B.  And since B's own creators accepted foundation layer C's license before building on it - that would be fine with them too.  And since it is fine with you: no problem.  If _you_ choose to use it and NOT cite it: whose ethics is implicated?

Comment: @davidbak a citation is a specific kind of signal that an author sends to her readers (with the implicit approval of the journal). The convention is that if author X cites work Y, then X believes work Y deserves to be cited and that the citation serves the needs of the readers and is not added gratuitously to serve someone’s ulterior motive. But now you are suggesting to create a legal framework whereby if author X cites work Z, they will also be legally required to cite work Y regardless of whether they believe adding such a citation is warranted and respects that convention. …

Comment: … This places on X a requirement that they cannot ethically and conscionably comply with. Nor can the journal publishing the work conscionably give its approval to this state of affairs. So, in such a situation X is forced to either not publish their work, not cite either Z or Y (which violates their ethical duty to cite Z), or cite Z but not Y (which violates their legal mandate to cite Y). All of these options hurt science (the last one doing so the least, hence it’s the one I would likely choose if forced to). Therefore the original requirement is unethical.

Comment: @DanRomik -  But if authors of the derivative software B accepted the license of C, THEY were saying that C was critical to their software B, and is deserving of recognition.  Whatever.  The OPs question was how to arrange that C got credit.  This is a way to arrange it.  Anyone who doesn't like it doesn't have to use C.  This doesn't hurt "science" any more than if C didn't exist in the first place.  If it didn't exist, B would have had to create it - maybe they wouldn't have done the work and then B wouldn't exist either.  Now, _that would_ hurt science.  Do what you want. Be moral for sure.

Comment: @davidbak interesting opinions, thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I support the answer of Alexander Woo, but would like to elaborate on "expert judgement rather than crude benchmarks". In my opinion the benchmarks will always be there, whether we want it or not. This is simply not practical to pull experts from their main jobs to do evaluation of other scientists.

Benchmarks deserve their existence. However, it is up to experts to devise clear criteria for the evaluations. One such criterion could be to exclude engineering and software engineering from the academic evaluations. We should evaluate academicians according to academic criteria, scientific programers according to 0.5 x software engineering + 0.5 x academic criteria, and programers according to industrial standards.

The problem is in the self-perception of scientific programmers. Very often they position themselves both in academic field and industry to maximize their chances of finding a job. Pure mathematicians, string theorists, philosophers, or social scientists do not have such an escape.

Answer (score 0):

The NIH asks applicants to fill out a "Biosketch" that is used to assess the qualifications of the PI (and other key members) of the proposal.

It asks for up to five "Contributions to Science", each of consists of a half-page of text and up to four references to "research products", which need not be publications or even your own work. This would be an ideal place for the authors of *C* to explain how their work underpins the more popular package *B*. Indeed, I've heard that people have had success doing something similar with data resources: "I collected/curated data set X, which others have used to do impactful things Y and Z." The one important caveat is that NIH does *not* allow hyperlinks in grants, so you can't directly link to the README, but I imagine you can allude to it.

Here's the [Biosketch Instructions](https://grants.nih.gov/grants/forms/biosketch.htm), which include a sample.